# How can i split string with number periods also, commas

Tags: c#

I have string like below

```
1. menggambarkan , mengecat , melukis;

2. menyalin , membuat; 

3. memotret , film , menjepret
```

How can I split them so the string became array of string the result will be like

```
menggambarkan
mengecat
melukis 
menyalin 
membuat
memotret 
film
menjepret
```

below is what i have already tried

```
input.Split(new string[] {  " , "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

but how can i remove number with dots like 1. 2. 3. and sign  ;

I think we can use `regex` for the solution, do u have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d+\.\s*");
var s = "1. menggambarkan , mengecat , melukis ; 2. menyalin , membuat; 3. memotret , film , menjepret";
var words = s.Split(new char[]{',', ';'}).Select(w => regex.Replace(w.Trim(), string.Empty));
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx approach to excract all words

```
string input = "1. menggambarkan , mengecat , melukis ; 2. menyalin , membuat; 3. memotret , film , menjepret";
string[] result = Regex.Matches(input, "[a-z]+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/mHf1eu

Comment: If you included the results directly in the answer without the need to run the fiddle then this would be a perfect answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, your code is good but it seems, it also split by space, right ? i test with this

Comment: i tried with this             string input = "1. menggambarkan , mengecat , melukis ; 2. menyalin , membuat; 3. memotret , film , menjepret 4. yaqut ( jenis permata ) merah";

Comment: the result should be 

menggambarkan,
mengecat,
melukis,
menyalin,
membuat,
memotret,
film,
menjepret,
yaqut ( jenis permata ) merah,

komma means new lines (because in comment cannot make new line)

Comment: You don't need the Cast<Match>

Comment: Can you fix that ?

Comment: @San-TrenRepository update your question. The splitting condition is not clear. `;` should also result into a new line?

Answer (score 0):

Something along this line. You have to remove the matched empty line.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string URL = " 1. menggambarkan , mengecat , melukis ; 2. menyalin , membuat ; 3. memotret , film , menjepret";

        string[] splitString = Regex.Split(URL, @"[(\s;\s\d.\s)(\s\d.\s)(\s,\s)]");  

        foreach (var item in splitString)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(item);  
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a `Linq`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "1. menggambarkan , mengecat , melukis ; 2. menyalin , membuat; 3. memotret , film , menjepret";
        str = new string((from c in str
                  where char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetter(c)
                  select c
       ).ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        string[] array = str.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Console.WriteLine(array.Count());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
menggambarkan  mengecat  melukis   menyalin  membuat  memotret  film  menjepret
8
```